# Consulta simples MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenha a consulta:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM cliente,
       categoria_cliente,
       categoria
 WHERE categoria_cliente_cliente_id = cliente_id 
   and categoria_id = categoria_cliente_categoria_id
   and (categoria_cliente_categoria_id = 1 OR categoria_cliente_categoria_id = 2)
 GROUP BY cliente_id
```

Se faço ela com o `OR` no `WHERE`, funciona perfeitamente, mas se troco o `OR` por `AND` não vem nenhum registro.

O que preciso em questão é o seguinte:

Trazer os clientes que estão na tabela `categoria_cliente`, nesta tabela, tem a coluna `categoria_cliente_cliente_id` e `categoria_cliente_categoria_id`, com o `OR` estou trazendo clientes que estejam na categoria 1 ou 2, mas, com o `AND` eu quero trazer apenas os clientes que esteja com o categoria 1 e 2.

Comment: Ainda bem né, pois se a `categoria_cliente_categoria_id` for 1 e for 2 ao mesmo tempo (AND) temos um problema no universo.

Comment: Agora, se você conseguir explicar um pouco melhor sobre o tipo de campo, se é numérico, se tem texto, etc, podemos tentar ajudar de maneira mais objetiva, claro. Por exemplo, se categoria for texto, separado com virgulas, já não pode ser com =. Mas pra isso, seria bom você [edit] a pergunta dando mais detalhes. O MySQL tem o FIND_IN_SET se for para vários valores. Exemplo: `FIND_IN_SET( 1, categoria_cliente_categoria_id) AND FIND_IN_SET( 2, categoria_cliente_categoria_id)`

Comment: Assumo que 1 cliente pode per mais do que uma categoria, isso é, você tem entradas em `categoria_cliente` com o mesmo `categoria_cliente_cliente_id`, porém diferentes   `categoria_cliente_categoria_id` correto? Nesse caso você gostaria que a consulta retornasse apenas clientes associados a ambas as categorias, é isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com a seguinte query, está retornando todos os clientes ja relacionados com todas as categorias:

```
SELECT cli.*, cat.*
  FROM cliente cli
  JOIN categoria_cliente cc
    ON cc.categoria_cliente_cliente_id = cli.cliente_id
  JOIN categoria cat
    ON cat.categoria_id = cc.categoria_cliente_categoria_id
 ORDER BY cli.cliente_id
```

Se quiser clientes que estejam nas cagorias 1 **OU** 2, fica:

```
SELECT cli.*, cat.*
  FROM cliente cli
  JOIN categoria_cliente cc
    ON cc.categoria_cliente_cliente_id = cli.cliente_id
  JOIN categoria cat
    ON cat.categoria_id = cc.categoria_cliente_categoria_id
   AND cat.categoria_id IN (1, 2)
 ORDER BY cli.cliente_id
```

Se quiser clientes que estejam nas cagorias 1 **E** 2, fica:

```
SELECT cli.*, cat.*
  FROM cliente cli
  JOIN categoria_cliente cc
    ON cc.categoria_cliente_cliente_id = cli.cliente_id
  JOIN categoria cat
    ON cat.categoria_id = cc.categoria_cliente_categoria_id
   AND cat.categoria_id IN (1, 2)
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * 
                FROM categoria_cliente cc1 
               WHERE cc1.categoria_cliente_cliente_id = cli.cliente_id
                 AND cc1.categoria_cliente_categoria_id = 1)
   AND EXISTS(SELECT * 
                FROM categoria_cliente cc2
               WHERE cc2.categoria_cliente_cliente_id = cli.cliente_id
                 AND cc2.categoria_cliente_categoria_id = 2)
```

Comment: +1. [Essa resposta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7774879/664577) lista outras 12 opções de como fazer esse tipo de consulta - algumas infelizmente só funcionam no Postgre. A sua se encaixaria no modelo número 5. Eu geralmente faço isso com o modelo número 6, isso é, múltiplos joins para `categoria_cliente` com *aliases* filtrados por `categoria_cliente_categoria_id `.